# FEDAUTH Security Cookie

Tags: session-cookies

I have captured "FEDAUTH" security cookie (using Fiddler) while browsing my asp.net 3.5 site using IE 7 ,  Now I know that FEDAUTH security cookie is marked with a “HTTPOnly” flag, this means that you cannot access this cookie from code. All of the APIs in the stack honor this flag so you can’t get to the FEDAUTH token through code. But .NET includes a CookieContainer class that holds the collection of cookies sent and retrieved from a web request. So all you need to do is simply pass the CookieContainer along from call to call.

My question is can some one take this cookie and use it in a http request like

```
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
                cc.SetCookies(new Uri(_uri), "FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwgdmVyhcmVwb2ludC5jb2addfdQ8UD4=; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2010 02:37:12 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly");
```